# Ubuntu15.04 Installation Error Asus UX303LA

Tags: system-installation, asus, 15.04

My PC is an Asus UX303LA. During the installation process of Ubuntu 15.04 I have the following error message:

**Message in the window**: *trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin2.21-Oubuntu*

For the installation, I use *ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso* .

I did a test with Ubuntu 14.04 --> same error :-(

I don't know what are the information that you need, but please, here are few more info on my PC:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b95:7e2b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 054c:0243 Sony Corp. MicroVault Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f04c0
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
23 structures occupying 1638 bytes.
Table at 0x000EBD40.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: UX303LA.204
    Release Date: 09/01/2014
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 6144 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: UX303LA
    Version: 1.0      
    Serial Number: ECN0CJ026550498    
    UUID: 38F3960E-2C19-3944-89A3-7FA1C460CBB7
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: ASUS-Ultrabook
    Family: UX

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: UX303LA
    Version: 1.0      
    Serial Number: BSN12345678901234567
    Asset Tag: ATN12345678901234567
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: MIDDLE             
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: 1.0      
    Serial Number: ECN0CJ026550498    
    Asset Tag: No Asset Tag   
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 10, 26 bytes
On Board Device 1 Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  VGA
On Board Device 2 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  GLAN
On Board Device 3 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  WLAN
On Board Device 4 Information
    Type: Sound
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  Audio CODEC
On Board Device 5 Information
    Type: SATA Controller
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  SATA Controller
On Board Device 6 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  USB 2.0 Controller
On Board Device 7 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  USB 3.0 Controller
On Board Device 8 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  SMBus Controller
On Board Device 9 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  Card Reader
On Board Device 10 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  Cmos Camera
On Board Device 11 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description:  Bluetooth

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: beirUyPK-pzG6
    String 2: 8ZZ6W0xHjbMEw
    String 3: ohAtvU0T6jipw
    String 4: 90NB04Y1-M01340
    String 5: 
    String 6: 
    String 7: 
    String 8: 
    String 9: 
    String 10: 

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: DSN:412465042005                   
    Option 2: DSN:FFFFFFFFFFFF                   
    Option 3: DSN:FFFFFFFFFFFF                   
    Option 4: SMI:00B2CA

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: SOCKET 0
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i7
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: 51 06 04 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 69, Stepping 1
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Voltage: 1.2 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 3800 MHz
    Current Speed: 2000 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket rPGA988B
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x000A
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0009
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x000B
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Fill By OEM
    Part Number: Fill By OEM
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L2
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L1
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 128 kB
    Maximum Size: 128 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Other
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: CPU Internal L3
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 4096 kB
    Maximum Size: 4096 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Micron
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number:                  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000D
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0012
    Partition Row Position: Unknown
    Interleave Position: Unknown
    Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000C
    Partition Width: 4

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        88 06 18 00 00 00

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        83 40 19 00 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        F8 00 43 9C 00 00 00 00 01 20 00 00 05 00 09 00
        CE 06 14 00 00 00 00 00 C8 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 66 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

(Note: I'm really not an advanced Linux user.)

Many thanks for your help !!!! :-)

Comment: I have create a like to dropbox with a screenshot with the error message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/agff74mj6hj3lg1/Screenshot%20from%202015-04-30%2023_05_16.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you verifyed the image isn't broken with a checksum, or downlaoded the image again?

Comment: @ Pabi: thanks, I just did a "Check disc for defects" and the output message is "no erros found"

Comment: You can try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before starting the installation.

Comment: @Pabi: I did the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but I have still the same error message.

Comment: I can't think of a reason for that happening on a new installation. You are doing a fresh installation on an empty partition? Can you try another installation media (e.g. from usb stick)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took me 2 hours to figure out what it was.

In the USB stick I was using there were remaining deb files from a Debian distro in the hidden trash folder (.local/share/Trash/). I had erased the USB stick using nautilus and I did not worried about hidden files. Ubuntu in some way mapped those files into its apt repository and used in the install.

To solve this issue, I formated the USB stick and installed again the Ubuntu. I used UNetbootin. It worked!